# How do I stop a running python program or bypass gui to command line? Is there a keypress?

Tags: python

I have a python program that comes up at boot. It is a photobooth program designed to start whenever the raspi is powered up. 
I have set a crontab for it. 
It starts automatically.
I cannot get it to stop and restarting only runs the program again.
Can I boot to a command prompt?
Can I crash the GUI so I have a command line?
Can I stop a running Python program with some operation? 
I pressed every key I could think of at startup and the raspi switched into read only mode, so I cannot edit the python file.  grr. 
The ip is set to a fixed address that conflicts with another computer on the lan so I cannot Putty in.  Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, one of the easiest way would be to edit your crontab file in order to remove the line that launch your script :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And then reboot your pi.

If you still want to launch your script at startup but you want to kill it for any reasons, this could help you : https://superuser.com/questions/446808/how-to-manually-stop-a-python-script-that-runs-continuously-on-linux

It explains how to identify the process number of your python script and then how to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the SD card and mount it elsewhere and edit the crontab to disable it from coming up.

If you used crontab -e to do this, then look for the file in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/(username)  presumably "pi"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can press Ctr-C if the program is currently running in the shell.